# Efficient approach for language tags (small tag set) in rdbms queries

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, database-schema, rdbms

My app uses an RDBMS (postgres w/ activerecord) to store and fetch text objects. Each text object can have any number of languages associated with it. So far I've been thinking of these language associations as tags in my head, much like blog posts can have any number of arbitrary tags. However, these language tags are not arbitrary, and are instead limited to a small set of about 30. In my app a user can request some text objects and supply a set of languages (say English, German, and French) and the app should go ahead and grab some text objects associated with ANY of those languages.

What's the most effective approach/schema for associating languages with these text objects to make querying easy?

Comment: SQL Server handles `xs<-x_tag->tags` just fine, as should any modern RDBMS. I also find it is the simplest conceptually: that is, "scalability issues" can be addressed later - *make sure the model correctly captures all the desired information in a normalized manner*. (Jeff Atwood also wrote an article on tags and how they are used/implemented in SO; it might be worth searching for.)

Comment: Arrays support indexing on the "contains" operator `@>`; see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html . `hstore` with dummy values for the keys would also do the job and its GiST index support may prove better than array's GIN if you have high write load. In both cases you can use a `CHECK` constraint to limit values.

Comment: @pst: that's what I ended up going with, although I couldn't find the Jeff Atwood article.

Comment: @kevboh I can't find it either :( It looks like the current [SO main schema](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema) stores de-normalized tags. I was sure I read something about "tag clusters" as well, but I can't seem to find such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easy to query you can create a view to avoid the constant joining.

```
create table object (
    id serial unique,
    object text primary key
);

create table tag (
    id serial unique,
    tag text primary key
);

create table object_tag (
    object_id integer references object(id),
    tag_id integer references tag(id)
);

insert into tag (tag) values ('English'), ('French'), ('German');
insert into object (object) values ('o1'), ('o2');
insert into object_tag (object_id, tag_id) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3);

create view v_object_tag as
select o.id object_id, o.object, t.id tag_id, t.tag
from
    object o
    inner join
    object_tag ot on o.id = ot.object_id
    inner join
    tag t on t.id = ot.tag_id
;
```

Now query as if it were a single table:

```
select *
from v_object_tag
where tag in ('English', 'German')
;
 object_id | object | tag_id |   tag   
-----------+--------+--------+---------
         1 | o1     |      1 | English
         2 | o2     |      3 | German
```